# PHP - Symfony2.4 Can I have multiple classes in single file?

Tags: php, symfony, code-reuse

I am using [Vzaar](https://vzaar.com/)'s [PHP Library](https://code.google.com/p/vzaar/) for uploading videos from my website to their server space.

Now point is - in their library there are some PHP files in which more than one class exists and no class with same file name exists in same file.

i.e. have a look at [OAuth.php](http://vzaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/api/php/trunk/OAuth.php), there is no class with name `OAuth` in that file.

Question raised in my mind is

When I create any PHP class file, can I create multiple classes in side one file, and later I can use that file in my code or I can use that reusable code in other project as well.

Should creating such files is good practice?

If the class is of 15 to 20 lines long, then should I create a separate file or I should include that in one file only, like OAuth.php.

Please guide with exact reason, if I will get links of wiki where proper explanation is given, then it will be best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting more than one class in one file in general is a bad practice, and in Symfony2 even more because of the way class autoloader works.

When autoloader is looking for `Acme\DemoBundle\SomeClass` class it expects it will be in `Acme\DemoBundle\SomeClass.php` file. So in case you have a second class in the same file it won't work.

Check also [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) standards for class autoloading.

Comment: Yes this is correct, but many third party libraries come with many class in one file structure. and I don't what they want to achieve, by writing classes of 5 lines in which only 3 to 4 member variables exists, nothing else, example is same library, any way thanks for your input @Tomasz

Answer (score 4):

Despite I don't like to define more than one class per file I would like to point it out that PSR-4 is not against this practice if the class scope is private.

Quoting Symfony2 coding standards resource (http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html)

> Define one class per file - this does not apply to private helper
>   classes that are not intended to be instantiated from the outside and
>   thus are not concerned by the PSR-0 and PSR-4 autoload standards;

In this other example (Thanks to Xavi Montero) you can see that the class `Psr4AutoloaderClassTest` has a helper class `MockPsr4AutoloaderClass` defined in the same file. So in general you should not, but for a "private helper" it's okey.
https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples

Comment: In this PSR-4 sample page https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/ you can see that, for instance, the class `Psr4AutoloaderClassTest` has a helper class `MockPsr4AutoloaderClass` defined in the same file. So in general you should not, but for a "private helper" it's okey.

Comment: Thank you for that comment Xavi, I'm adding it to enrich the answer.